# Troubleshooting clang error to get C++ code in CLion to work

Tags: clion, clang++

I'm an inexperienced programmer so bear with me if this little sense. I'm trying to run a basic "hello world" kind of program in CLion, except I'm trying to print out a value in the main.cpp file from a header and cpp file. I'm using MacOS and everything is update in terms of software. When I try to build or run the program, it gives me these errors:

```
====================[ Build | untitled1 | Debug ]===============================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/anshuldaga/untitled1/cmake-build-debug --target untitled1 -- -j 2
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/test.cpp.o
make[3]: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++: Permission denied
make[3]: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [untitled1] Error 2
```

I've already tried running the sudo g++ main.cpp command and it gives me this error:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Based off my research, I know that clang is the compiler for c++ and a linker error is basically when something can't find the right files or library.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode, did the

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

command. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203856790-Clion-doesnt-compile-on-MacOS-Sierra)([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190611204258/https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203856790-Clion-doesnt-compile-on-MacOS-Sierra)) old post from the CLion forum, the xcode license agreement might be the issue. Try to start xcode and agree to the license, or run `sudo xcodebuild -license`.